# How would i design processing twitter data

Tags: data, scalability, system, twitter

I am working on a project where a user can input different criteria which will be used to fetch tweets, lets call this action as `TweetAnalysis`. These tweets will then be sent to another internal system (REST API) to do some calculation and get results. Each tweet will have a unique result from REST API. For each `TweetAnalysis` created by users, there could be million of tweets and each tweet can have their respective results returned from API. (only 2 values from the results are aggregatable, every other value of the result is unique between tweets)

How would i design such a system?

What I was thinking is

- User creates a `TweetAnalysis` (let's call it `TA`) and it is stored in db.
- A separate process picks up a `TA` and retrieve all the respective tweets for it. These tweets can be dumped into an `S3` object? While doing so, the S3 objects will be unique for each `TA` and can be broken down into chunks of 1000 tweets?
- A separate process can pick up those `S3` objects, gather their respective info from `REST API` system and persist the values in db?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but much too broad. You seem to consider using S3 as a kind of processing pipeline.  So I'd recommend to you take a look at [Streaming data](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22892595-streaming-data), an excellent book about real-time data pipelines that need to scale.  Given your domain, it would be a real investment, as it covers all the aspects you'll need to ba aware of.